# How to clamp a float using other floats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, floating-point, clamp

I know this may sound like quite a dumb question, sorry, but is it possible to clamp a float, using other floats. ie:

```
public float float1;
public float float2 -1;
public float float3 1;

void Start()
{
   Mathf.Clamp (float1, float2, float3)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes it is, [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) has two overloads:

> public static float Clamp(float value, float min, float max);
>
> public static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max);

But, well you have to assign the result to something ;)

```
float1 = Mathf.Clamp (float1, float2, float3);
```

and your declarations are missing `=`

```
public float float1;
public float float2 = -1;
public float float3 = 1;
```

Comment: thanks, that was why it wasn't working, I'll keep this is mind for next time :)

Comment: also, sorry to bother you again but do you put mathf.clamp in the start function or the update function or both?

Comment: @CyberScope_ I'd say that pretty much depends on where you need it ^^ If you put it into `Start` it is only applied once and any later change on these fields doesn't matter ... if you need to continously clamp this every frame then it goes into `Update`

Comment: Thanks again I think I understand also thanks for reminding me about the equal signs 